# Running and building Pytorch on Google Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a python package that requires `pytorch-gpu`. I have change the runtime type of my Colab notebook to GPU. When I run the command, I am facing the following error. Not sure if I am able to build pytorch on colab myself?

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inference_unet.py", line 9, in <module>
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .extension import _HAS_OPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/extension.py", line 58, in <module>
    _check_cuda_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/extension.py", line 54, in _check_cuda_version
    .format(t_major, t_minor, tv_major, tv_minor))
RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and torchvision were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA Version=10.2 and torchvision has CUDA Version=10.1. Please reinstall the torchvision that matches your PyTorch install.
```

Answer (score 3):

Now you can directly use pytorch-gpu on google colab, no need of installation.
Just change your runtime to gpu, import torch and torchvision and you are done.
I have attached screenshot doing just the same.

Hope the answer will find helpful.

[image: ScreenShot of Importing Pytorch]

But in case you want to install different version of pytorch or any other package then you can install using pip, just add ! before your pip command and run the cell.

for example,
[image: running pip in notebook]